# Что такое "как есть"?

Tags: вводные-слова

Чем является конструкция "как есть" в таком предложении? Вводными словами или нет? И правильно ли расставлены запятые?

"Матершину забуду, как есть, всю забуду!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Матерщину забуду, как есть, всю забуду!***

**1. Структура оборота**

Исходная  грамматика оборота: Говорю (как?) ***так, как есть.*** Это СПП с придаточным образа действия.

*Говорю **как есть**.* По Розенталю: **Цельные** по смыслу выражения не отделяются и не выделяются запятыми.

**2. Значение оборота [по Фразеологическому  словарю](https://phraseology.academic.ru/4033/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)**

**Экспрес**. ***Как есть***

(1) В чём остался одет; как был.

Я опять было улёгся — как есть, в ботинках, но покоя уже не стало (И. Тарасович. Во время дождя). «Куда бечь, где укрыться? Стоим на мёрзлой земле, от страха и слёзы, нейдут. В минуту остались мы безо всего, как есть. Были крестьяне, были колхозники, а сделались беженцы» (Н. Баранская. Аксинья Кузьминична).

(2) **Совсем; абсолютно (всё, ничего).**

Так было много детей, что когда король разделил всем сыновьям свои богатства, то младшему-то сыну ничего не досталось. Как есть ничего не досталось, ни одежды, ни лошадей (Куприн. Сказка).

(3) Настоящий; подлинный. — Лошадь настоящая. — Как есть, — сказал Никита (Л. Н. Толстой. Хозяин и работник).

**4. Решение задачи**

***Матерщину забуду, как есть, всю забуду!***

Исходное предложение: *Матерщину забуду, **полностью**, **всю**  забуду!*

Значение оборота: абсолютно (полностью) всё.

**Однородные отношения:** как есть (= полностью), всю. **Запятая ставится.**

**Экспрессию** создает двойной повтор:  действия (забуду) и его признака (всю, полностью).

Это член предложения,  поэтому  **не является вводным словом.**

**4. Может ли оборот "как есть" быть вводным словом**

Другими словами, может ли оборот приобрести функцию вводного слова? Может, конечно, ведь это **экспрессивное слово.** Но предложение должно быть так **построено**, чтобы оборот стал **"авторской пометкой"** с нужным значением, но не членом предложения.

Что касается этого приложения, то у него структура **неопределенная,** поэтому  возможны **два варианта прочтения:**

(1) Матерщину забУду, // как Есть, //  всЮ забуду! **Член предложения**.

(2) Матерщину забУду, // как есть, всЮ забуду! **Вводное слово** со значением "точно говорю", оно не выделено ударением.

Comment: Спасибо!
Уточните ещё, пожалуйста, в п. 2 пример из Куприна. "Как есть ничего не досталось" без запятых пишется. В моём случае это объяснение? Но у меня запятые стоят правильно. Почему в примере тогда их нет? Я запуталась...

Comment: Здесь надо смотреть структуру предложения и расстановку ударений в нем. (1) Как Есть ничего не досталось, ни одЕжды, ни лошадЕй.   Это член предложения (обстоятельство) в ударной позиции. 
(2) СРАВНИМ: АбсолЮтно, как Есть ничего не досталось. Это однородные члены.  (3)  Ему действИтельно ничего не досталось ? Как есть, ни одЕжды, ни лошадей.  Это вводное слово ( = точно говорю).

Comment: ПРАКТИЧЕСКАЯ рекомендация. Оборот приравниваем к одному слову-синониму по его значению  (абсолютно, полностью и т.д.), а вводное слово приравниваем к «точно говорю». Подставляем в предложение и на слух определяем нужный вариант. Ошибиться здесь сложно: одно слово просто так обычно не обособляется, в отличие от «точно говорю». Матерщину забуду, полностью, всю забуду!  Матерщину забуду,точно говорю, всю забуду! Здесь запятые ставятся одинаково в обоих случаях.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

На [грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_339#:%7E:text=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%C2%AB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) говорят, что фразеологизм **как пить дать** является наречным выражением и обособляется на усмотрение автора:
"Матершину забуду, как пить дать, всю забуду!"

Но здесь **как пить дать** синонимично **действительно**, а мы знаем, что это обстоятельство невозможно отличить от вводного слова:

> Слова и сочетания слов, которые в функции вводного  и в другой функции
> имеют одно и то же значение. Даже по  контексту **невозможно различить**,
> в какой функции употреблено  то или иное слово: все зависит от желания
> автора - либо  подчеркнуть свою субъективность, либо использовать
> слово  в свойственной ему функции. Например: по крайней мере, в
> известном смысле, **действительно**, между тем, во всяком  случае, на
> первый взгляд, так или иначе.

Так что можно трактовать и как вводное.

На самом деле многие вводные слова можно считать не вводными:

```
Он думал, я уйду. // не вводное, поправьте если я не прав 
Я думаю, я уйду.   // вводное
```

Наше **как есть** примерно из той же серии. Его можно заменить на **клянусь**, у которого статус 100% вводное, но опять таки, такое вводное может легко стать не вводным.

PS Ну и немного о значении фразеологизма **как есть**. Вот его значение по [словарям синонимов](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/58499/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA)

> буквально, в буквальном смысле слова, в прямом смысле слова
> (Словарь русских синонимов.)

> нареч, кол-во синонимов: 3 • буквально (26) • в буквальном смысле
> слова (5) • в прямом смысле слова (3) (Словарь синонимов ASIS. В.Н. Тришин. 2013.)

Сами словари лежат [тут](https://synonymonline.ru/download.html)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147318/discussion-on-answer-by-user190920----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

> ...ибо оные присылаются от Канцелярии в Экспедицию и так, как есть, печатаются. Ломоносов.

Думаю здесь подобный случай, и, наверное, вводное.

> «А пан думает, что так прямо взял кобылу, запряг да и: «эй, ну, пошел, сивка!» Думает пан, что можно так, как есть, не спрятавши, везти пана?» Гоголь. Тарас Бульба.

Как есть ~ ничего не меняя/не меняясь. Выделяется запятыми.

> Ты скажешь, может быть, что много есть богатых глупцов и лентяев в то время, как есть умные и деятельные люди. М. Н. Загоскин. Искуситель (1838)

Как есть ~ сами/само. Не выделятся.

> Ленивица притащила ему кастрюлю, как есть, даже скатертцы не подостлала В. Ф. Одоевский. Сказки дедушки Иринея (1841)

Не меняя - оценка, выделяется.

> Не могу понять, как есть на свете люди, которые могут писать письма летом с Рейна и прилежащих к нему государств. П. В. Анненков. Письма из-за границы (1841-1843)

Как есть на свете люди - вопрос: как есть такое, такие? Не выделяется.

> ...спать не раздеваясь, так, как есть, в том же сюртуке... Гоголь

Не меняя, не снимая - выделяется.

Видимо, потому что "не есть иначе" - то есть отрицание, выражение несогласия. Надо мол, не так делать.

> Три девицы вскочили в суматохе с постели как есть и задувают свечку… Гончаров.

с постели как есть - то есть раздетые. Утверждение. Так случилось, вскочили же. Не надо запятых.

> Мой замок стоит как есть уж несколько веков. В. А. Соллогуб. Тарантас (1845)

мой замок стоял и будет стоять - он есть. Утверждение, без запятых.

Наиболее подходящее, наверное:

> [Подхалюзин (муж, приказчик)] Уж одно слово: вот как есть, весь тут. А. Н. Островский. Свои люди ― сочтемся (1849)
> [Устинья Наумовна (жен, сваха)] Вышел как есть в одном шлафорке; а уж употчевал ― можно чести приписать. Островский. Свои люди ― сочтемся (1849)

...

Я склоняюсь к тому, что "Матершину забуду, как есть, всю забуду!" - не очень корректное употребление, создающее порадоксы. Потому что есть - это всегда. Нельзя сказать "забуду как есть" в смысле "всю", можно сказать забуду "что есть", а не "как есть".

"Матершину забуду, что есть - всю забуду!"